# Calculus: L′ Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, self-learning

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{\tan x}$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x^2\ln x$
3. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^+}x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$

Do I have to apply l'Hôpital's Rule to evaluate these limits?

Comment: Could you tell us your opinion ?

Comment: It provides the simplest path for the first two, and works for the third. But the third can be done faster without.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Careful!  It may help to get the limit into the correct form for l'Hopital's Rule, but it might not always be applicable.  I'm ashamed to admit I'm not sure if l'Hopital's Rule could be used for the third, but I think I see another way of doing it.

Comment: Oops.  Forget what I said on number 3.  For some reason, I was thinking the negative part would be inside the logarithm...

Comment: So, for 1), is the answer  $0$? And for 2), is it  $1/e$?

Comment: @user100523 For 1) the limit is 1, For 2) the limit is 0, for 3) it is 1/e.

Comment: For 3) let $x=1+\frac{1}{t}$.

Answer (score 2):

For the second limit: Yes
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\log x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log x}{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac  1x}{-2x^{-3}}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 12x^2=0$$
and for the other limits it's more simple to use the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

In 1. and 3., take the logarithm of the function and then write it as a fraction.

In 2., $x^2\ln x=\dfrac{x^2}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$.